# What is the best way to update state inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Since setState works asynchronously, it does not update the state immediately. How do I update a state variable inside a loop.

The functionality is to validate multiple fields and to store if the field value is valid for a particular row index. However since the state changes do not reflect immediately, I am not receiving the desired output.

Please suggest the best way to handle this.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
`setState` supports a callback function for chaining the async actions.

Comment: Your state may be an object or an array, so try to not setState at each iteration, instead setstate the whole array or object

Comment: @sidali - Yes I have tried in a similar manner. However the issue is that I have 4 different child fields dependent on a parent field. In case parent field changes, I need to validate the dependent fields in a loop. All the four fields have respective state arrays. How do I use callback in this scenario?

Comment: Try to use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) during the loop and update the state at the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storing the data using ref(s) and updating the state at the end has solved the issue.

Comment: How you did it? Can you share?

Comment: @Arnab would be super interested to know too

Comment: Interested to know as well

Answer (score 0):

you are right.. `setState` works asynchronously. So there is no point calling it multiple times inside a loop or anywhere except at the end of your code block. Not a best practice either.

So what you can do is, have a copy of this state variable defined before your loop. Do whatever you wanna do with this variable inside the loop. At the end, you can just update your state with this updated variable for once.

This way you wouldn't have to use `setState` multiple times, also you can get the updated state inside the loop from the dummy variable.